# Two Bootstrap Modals with Tabs Within

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have been successfully using  bootstrap modal/pop up for quite a long time. But here is an interesting case that totally surprised me.

If you have a modal with tabs inside of it, then I get expected results. It works as it should.

But if you have more then one modals with tabs, then one first modal works correctly. Tabs inside of others are not responding.

[image]

You can see example in the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap - Modal Demo With Tabs</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h5 style="text-align: center;">Bootstrap - Modal Demo - With Tabs Within</h5>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h4>Page One Modal #1 - Basic</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Page One Modal #1</a>
        </div>
     
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h4>Page One Modal #2 - Large</h4>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#largeModal">Page One Modal #2</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
            </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          
          <div class="tab-v2">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
              <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#info" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
              <li><a href="#survey" data-toggle="tab">Survey</a></li>
            </ul>
          
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="about">
              <br>
              <p>About Us</p>
              </div>
          
              <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="info">
              <br>          
              <p>Information</p>          
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="survey">
                <br>
                 <p>Survey</p>
              </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
         
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="largeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="largeModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Large Modal</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h3>Modal Body</h3>
          </div>
          
          
          <div class="tab-v2">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
              <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#info" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
              <li><a href="#survey" data-toggle="tab">Survey</a></li>
            </ul>
          
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="about">
              <br>
              <p>About Us 2</p>
              </div>
          
              <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="info">
              <br>          
              <p>Information 2</p>          
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="survey">
                <br>
                 <p>Survey 2</p>
              </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the same IDs in both tabs.

Change IDs of the second tab to for example `about-2`, `info-2` and `survey-2`. Don't forget to change `href` attributes too.

```
<div class="tab-v2">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li><a href="#about-2" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#info-2" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#survey-2" data-toggle="tab">Survey</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="about-2">
    <br>
    <p>About Us 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="info-2">
    <br>          
    <p>Information 2</p>          
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="survey-2">
    <br>
    <p>Survey 2</p>
  </div>

</div>
```